# Logged in user data, after logout

Tags: users

I need the ID of the logged in user, after logging out. I tried to use a session variable, but all data is lost on exit.
Is there any method to use, other than the query parameter?

```
┌──────────────┐                        ┌──────────────┐
│              │                        │              │
│  Page        │       ┌────────┐       │  Page        │
│              │       │        │       │              │
│  generation  │ ────► │ logout │ ────► │  generation  │
│              │       │        │       │              │
│  (UID: ?)    │       └────────┘       │  (UID: 0)    │
│              │                        │              │
└──────────────┘                        └──────────────┘
```

What is original user ID?

Comment: I don't understand - a logged out user only has an ID of 0. You would need to do some work in the user logout event/hook - but I am not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Kevin Please see edited question.

Answer (score 4):

`user_logout()` contains `\Drupal::service('session_manager')->destroy();` there is no chance of recovering the session after that. You need to set a cookie with the user id of the currently logged in user in `hook_user_logout`. Luckily the hook gets the `$user` as argument.